SElinux causes systemd-networkd.service to fail | Ubuntu 22.04
I have launched a clean virtual machine running Ubuntu 22.04. I wanted to secure it using SElinux, but when I go to enforce it and reboot, dbus.service, systemd-networkd.service and systemd-resolved.service fail. which leads to my VM to lose its IP address. I have tried this on Ubuntu 20.04 and same thing occurred. When I run setenforce 0 everything works fine again.

I want to launch an Ubuntu instance secured by SElinux on a cloud VPS, but if the network services fail I will not be able to ssh into the instance which is my main concern).
